# MySQL I/O Performance in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, database-connection

Is there a way to monitor MySQL I/O performance in XAMPP?

I am building an application that will interface with the MySQL database and for testing in XAMPP MySQL, I would like to be able to monitor I/O performance.

Comment: As a clarification to the question, I am using PHPMyAdmin to administer the MySQL database - does that have an administration tool for measuring I/O performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP does not have a performance monitoring tool built in for Mysql, since it is a web server and just comes packaged with Mysql when installed.  There are a number of free and paid ways to monitor I/O performance for Mysql.

If you are on a linux server you can use iostat, htop, innotop, show innodb engine status and a number of other packages to monitor I/O performance yourself.  Here is a [Useful link](http://www.tecmint.com/mysql-performance-monitoring/).

[Mysql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) is free and has a Dashboard where you can see performance.

[Monyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog) is another great tool but is not free and requires some setup.  However, the performance monitoring for a DBA is worth the effort, especially if you have dozens of sites.

Comment: Hi Michael,

I personally recommend Navicat Monitor.  (https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-monitor)  It uses an agentless architecture so you don't have to install any software on your monitored servers.

In addition to database metrics, It also collects process metrics such as CPU load, RAM usage, and a variety of other resources over SSH/SNMP.

Although Navicat Monitor is not a free product, I think that you'll find that it's well worth the price.

Thanks!

Rob G